# Opening new terminal window does not pick up .cshrc

Tags: linux, shell, tcsh, konsole

I am using KDE and Konsole. When I open a new tab, it does not pick up my .cshrc in my home directory. I am using tcsh. How I do I force re-loading of the .cshrc in my home directory without having to `source` everytime?

Answer (score 1):

Even though `tcsh` is compatible with `csh`, you could try renaming it to `.tcshrc`. It shouldn't be a problem though.

Or maybe you could start Konsole like this:

```
konsole -e tcsh -l
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that my environment was using `tcsh` and sourced `.tcshrc-personal`. I added the necessary parameters to my `.tcshrc-personal` that I needed and now I have no problems.